# Include module for typings but exclude from final webpack bundle?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm new to the Webpack world and have been working with TypeScript 1.x for a little while. Historically, I've done most of my TypeScript work all in one module (separate files), used TSD for typings, and compiled using a Gulp task.

I'm working on a new project and trying to set up a Webpack + TypeScript 2 (and imports / @types for typings) process. I'm finding some success, but I'd like to exclude certain libraries from my webpack bundle.

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
components/
   customComponentA/
   customComponentB/
node_modules/
   @types/
       angular/
main.ts
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

If I include `import * as angular from "angular";` in my custom components, I see a bunch of `Can't resolve 'angular'` issues (which makes sense). Once I actually add `angular` to my `node_modules`, Webpack is happy, but then all of Angular is included in my final bundle.

I want my typings to be happy *without* including Angular in my final bundle. Is this possible?

Comment: You will likely find this helpful: https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the documentation was quite helpful: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Answering for any new webpack users who may be trying to figure this out as well :)